# Add tag specific popup to [accidents]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags

It appears that [Tag Specific Popups](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6617/should-we-enable-tag-specific-popups) are available for use across the network, and apparently they're 'trivial' to add.

Should/could we add one to [accidents](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accidents)? Someone can post an answer with some suggested text, but something along the lines of 'no speculating, no questions til accident report complete, try to genericise the question, etc.'

> [image]

Comment: Feel free to ping me when you have some copy for the popup.

Comment: Can you explain how this would help?

Comment: @raptortech97 There are frequently a number of questions being posted immediately after accidents, most of which need heavily editing. There are a few questions here on Meta about it.

Comment: Hi @JonEricson - would you be so kind as to implement this for us please? :) Cheers!

Comment: Done. Let me know if anything needs changing.

Comment: Looks great @JonEricson, thanks! I don't suppose we can have a red background like on SO, rather than off-brown? Or is this something specific to beta sites?

Comment: I don't know what the background color is, but I believe it's related to the beta site theme. Is red the right choice? Seems a bit aggressive for a warning.

Comment: That's a good point @JonEricson - not to worry anyway; the text is the main thing. Hopefully it helps with the flurry of questions we get after accidents. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Makes senses @2mkgz!

Comment: Thanks @JonEricson! Looks neat!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My suggestion:

> Tip: Questions about accidents get better answers if they:
>
> - are specific (don't just ask "what happened?")
> - can be answered factually and accurately (speculating about accidents that have just happened is explicitly [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))
> - refer to reliable sources like aviation authorities and official accident reports
> - focus on the aviation aspects of the accident

Comment: as SentryRaven added to mine, I think that a reference to the off-topic page could be added also to this proposal (in particular at the first or second bullet).

Comment: @Federico That sounds good, I updated it

Answer (score 7):

**I am in support of this.** Normally I would say that we have the on-topic page to make clear what is accepted and what is not accepted on Aviation.SE, but given the amount of accident questions after real accidents, I would say this is a subtle reminder, which could help the OP reconsider or rephrase their question to meet our on-topic guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

I agree as well and this is my suggestion for the tip:

> Tip: questions about accidents get better answers if they:
>
> - are posed in a general way (focus on aspects that are relevant for the aviation community)
> - refer to official/reliable sources (Investigating authorities, final reports, AvHerald) and not to hearsay
> - don't ask for speculation or post speculation (e.g., "what could have happened?"): this is [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Feel free to add anything that I might have missed

Comment: This looks good, but "don't focus on a specific accident" is a bit difficult. After all, there can be good, well-answered questions about specific accidents (like [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2685/62)) and there's nothing wrong with asking about a particular accident if the question is precise and answerable (and not based on rumours, speculation etc.)

Comment: @Pondlife Any suggested different wording? I see what you mean, but I struggle to find a good wording...

Comment: @SentryRaven Yes, it's not easy. I was going to edit Federico's answer, but I posted my own instead so that people can see as many options as possible

Comment: @Federico Yes, I think that's better, and also a bit shorter and clearer which is probably a good thing for a pop-up!