# Should we have a tag popup also for "accident-investigation"?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags

In the last few days there have been a few questions using the [accident-investigation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident-investigation) tag that deal with an ongoing investigation and thus tend to be borderline on topic, if not fully off-topic.

Should we have a tag popup similar to [the one we have](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/1467) for the [accidents](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accidents) tag?

Comment: Yes, please......

Comment: At first glance this seems like a sensible idea. The other option would be to merge the tags (make [tag:accidents] a synonym for [tag:crash-investigation]) but I don't think that's a correct solution.

Comment: @voretaq7 the popup text would be different, imho the tags should remain separate.

Comment: @Federico The pop-up text could actually be the same; I wrote it (with your help!) with this scenario in mind. And I agree the tags should be remain separate, I don't think they're the same thing.

Comment: @Pondlife well, the tag has a different usage, so I would adjust the text.

Comment: @Federico Yes, that's true. Some minor change would probably be enough.

Comment: @JonEricson can I ping you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would propose a pop-up text that would look like the following (simple adjustment of a few words from the [accidents](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accidents) pop-up):

> Tip: Questions about investigations get better answers if they:
>
> - are specific to a part of the investigation, rather than a blanket question (don't just ask "what happened?")
> - can be answered factually and accurately (speculating about ongoing investigations is explicitly [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))
> - refer to reliable sources like aviation authorities and official accident reports
> - focus on the aviation aspects of the accident

Comment: I think "are specific" is a little vague (ironically).  I would put something like "are specific to a part of the investigation, rather than a blanket question (such as, 'What happened?')"

Comment: @JayCarr thanks, added

Comment: I would be inclined to say "related to the investigation" rather than "a part of" - this way, you would encourage questions that are generally applicable to aviation (but were raised in relation to a recent accident) rather than questions that suggest theories based on the press reports during the investigation.

Comment: @sanchises Right, but the intent of the phrase "are specific to a part of the investigation" is to try and stop people from asking questions that are related to the accident, but are very broad.  So we're trying to stop people from saying, "Why did the plane crash?" and would prefer something like, "Why did CRM break down on flight AF447?"  Honestly, being more specific in this case will very much help, especially when you consider that most crashes are fairly singular events (so questions regarding them are unlikely to be widely applicable, no matter how hard we try.)

Comment: @JayCarr fair enough! ;)

Comment: if those downvoting don't comment or offer an alternative answer, it's kinda pointless.

Comment: Federico, not true, actually. This is a meta question of the "should we do some thing" variety. This is an answer to that question. Down-voting a meta answer can simply mean you don't agree with the direction of the answer, but are unable/unwilling to better explain. In other words, the down-voter likely disagrees with the "we should merge crash-investigation with accident-investigation", so is in effect casting his/her (wasn't me) vote to not merge. So, it's not pointless, but it's also not helpful, beyond the 'vote'.

Comment: @CGCampbell but the "we should merge" is not this question/answer

Comment: This is done, with the language specified here.